# Docker-compose up does not start a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM shawnzhu/ruby-nodejs:0.12.7

RUN \
    apt-get install git \   
    && npm install -g bower gulp grunt \
    gem install sass

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash devel

# Deal with ssh
COPY ssh_keys/id_rsa /devel/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY ssh_keys/id_rsa.pub /devel/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
RUN echo "IdentityFile /devel/.ssh/id_rsa" > /devel/.ssh/config

# set root password
RUN echo 'root:password' | chpasswd

# Add gitconfig
COPY .gitconfig /devel/.gitconfig

USER devel

WORKDIR /var/www/

EXPOSE 80
```

**docker-compose.yml file:**

```
nodejs:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "8001:80"
    - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
    - ~/Web/docker/nodejs/www:/var/www
```

**Commands:**

$ docker-compose build nodejs

$ docker images

```
REPOSITORY             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
nodejs_nodejs          latest              aece5fb27134        2 minutes ago       596.5 MB
shawnzhu/ruby-nodejs   0.12.7              bbd5b568b88f        5 months ago        547.5 MB
```

$ docker-compose up -d nodejs

```
Creating nodejs_nodejs_1
```

$ docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

$ docker ps --all

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
c24c6d0e756b        nodejs_nodejs       "/bin/bash"         About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                       nodejs_nodejs_1
```

As you can see the `docker-compose up -d` should have created a container and run it on the background, but it didn't. Instead it exited with code 0.

Comment: You Dockerfile don't start task

Comment: What should i add in the Dockerfile ?

Comment: For example you can add node start_server.js ? You understand why ?

Comment: No, i just want to run a container to ssh later inside, not doing extra stuffs

Comment: Ok, just run bash instance :) Docker stop container if it does nothing.

Comment: I've used `entrypoint: /bin/bash` for an image in docker-compose.yml, and still it's exited with 0 right after `docker-compose up` command

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your Dockerfile doesn't do anything (for example a webserver to listen on port 80), it will be discarded as soon as it finishes running the instructions. Because [Docker containers should be "ephemeral"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/).

If you just want to start a container and interact with it via terminal, don't use `docker-compose up -d`, use the following instead:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash [your_image_id]
```

This will start your container and run `/bin/bash`, the `-it` helps you keep the terminal session to interact with the container. When you are done doing your works, press `Ctrl-D` to exit.

Comment: solution is possible, but if you want to debug orcherstration, it's not very convenient solution. I've come to the following hack: add `entrypoint: tail /var/log/syslog` (for example; basically, any file that exists in an image) - this will not let the container exit immediately. PS: of course you should not need if you run any daemon in the container

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with SQL Server 2017 container exiting soon after it was created. The process running inside the container should be long running, otherwise Docker will exit the container. In the docker-compose scenario I implemented the tty:true approach which is documented here https://www.handsonarchitect.com/2018/01/docker-compose-tip-how-to-avoid-sql.html

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue while trying to use both Jenkins and Unity, as soon as the unityci Container was created, it exited, then the Jenkins one stayed up but with the other one to be manually started.